# how to trap/disable CTRL+C in GFORTH

Tags: forth, ctrl, gforth

how to trap/disable CTRL+C in GFORTH ?

I often use common case...endcase statement on key  but ctl+c is still possible to user.

I would add a function or something to disable it inside a word like

```
    : toto
\ do some stuff
\ <<---------- disable ctrl+c here 
key
81 of exitprog endof 
49 of manage1 endof
50 of manage2 endof
\ etc.
endcase
\ <<---------- enable ctrl+c back
;
```

or more efficient a way to trap it to a specific word execution

```
\ trap ctrl+c
: exitonctrlc dostuff 0 (bye) ;
```

I found no solution for that in official documentations 0.7.* version(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current Gforth version throws the code `-28` on Ctrl+C.

So if you want to get a code from `key` on Ctrl+C, you can just redefine `key` in your application word list as follows:

```
-28 constant key-ctrl-c-ior

: key ( -- x )
  ['] key catch dup key-ctrl-c-ior = if exit then throw
;
```

Now `key` returns quasi key code `-28` if the user presses Ctrl+C.

If you want to perform some actions on Ctrl+C before trap, you have to just `catch` your application main word (and don't redefine `key`), e.g.:

```
: main
  ['] main catch
  case ( ior )
    key-ctrl-c-ior of dostuff 0 (bye) endof
    \ ...
  endcase
;
```